# How do I use destroy within functions and classes - tkinter?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, destroy

I've seen some usage of `self.destroy()` within classes but I couldn't get it working with what I wanted it to do.

I have the class `resultsPage` that shows results obtained on another page. I have made the `displayResults(pageNo)` function to show these when `resultsPage` is visible. The problem arises with the back and next buttons which are made to go between pages of results. All widgets are created on top of each other but I want to remove them all then create the new ones. I added `self.destroy()` to try and fix this but it didn't work.

I'm not sure if it's to do with the placement of where I'm defining my functions but I have had a play around with where they're defined and it hasn't changed the error message.

This is a simplified example of my code:

```
class resultsPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    def onShowFrame(self, event):
        def displayResults(pageNo):
            self.destroy()
            #Create widgets related to pageNo
            #Create back and next buttons e.g.
            back = tk.Button(self, text="<=",
                                 command=lambda: displayResults(pageNo - 1))
        displayResults(1)
```

The error I get is: `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame.!previewresultspage"`

If it helps, I can post my full code but I thought I'd generalise it so it's more helpful to others.

Comment: Read [Switch between frames:`create=>use=>destroy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49325719/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl I had a read it but I couldn't get it working. I don't have anything called `master` to begin with and they haven't got it within `onShowFrame` which is what complicates things. I thought I might be able to use `parent` instead of `master` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you want such a **Switch between Frames** at all?

Comment: I have `showFrame` which allows me to switch between frames. However, I am actually having an issue with this when creating a home button within `onShowFrame` as the console says `NameError: name 'controller' is not defined`. So yes, I would like to be able to switch between frames and I also want to clear the `resultsPage` of all widgets upon calling `displayResults`.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the widget in `onShowFrame`, and then immediately try to create a new widget with it as the parent. You can't use a deleted widget as the parent of another widget.

Comment: How can I do what I described without using `self.destroy`?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, using `self.destroy()` in this case, will not work. To achieve the goal of deleting all widgets on the frame, you can use a loop (credit to @stovfl):

```
for widget in self.grid_slaves():
    widget.destroy()
```